# Use of Instants During Combat Phase

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I declare [Grizzly Bears](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGrizzly%20Bears%5d) as an attacker. My opponent moves to declare blockers, and decides to block the bears with an [Air Elemental](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAir%20Elemental%5d). Looking at the creature’s power and toughness, I notice my bears are going to die, so I cast [Titanic Growth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTitanic%20Growth%5d) in order to make my bears more powerful. But, in response to my last spell, opponent casts [Shock](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShock%5d) in order to kill the bears before the titanic growth resolves. In such a situation, do the Bears deal their 2 damage to Air Elemental, as the fight has been done just the same, or do the bears go directly to the graveyard without dealing their damage to the blocking creature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Combat damage no longer uses the stack](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rulestips/2011/04/combat-damage-does-not-use-the-stack/), so no: your Bears don't do 2 damage. Before the M2010 rules update, the Bears would indeed do 2 damage.

Comment: I'm waiting for other answers - if them will be there - before accepting this one,but I'm sure it is a good answer. I have been stuck in this kind of change in rulings too many times, and this could be one more time for me to do this.

Comment: Said this, the only possibility for the bears to deal their 2 damage and survive is to use something like healing salve (more than only one...).  It is correct?

Comment: @Massimiliano still dead because Shock kills the Bears before they deal damage. But there are tons of ways in which the bears can survive and still do damage, e.g. with a Vivien Reid emblem.

Comment: Healing Salve should work fine; preventing the damage that would be done by Shock.

Comment: @Massimiliano There are plenty of ways. Casting another Titanic Growth would work.

Comment: @GendoIkari as I understand the question, the attacker sees their Grizzle Bears is going to die, so to prevent it from dying, they cast Healing Salve. Opponent responds with Shock. In that case the Bears are still dead.

Comment: GendoIkari I know the line you notice some days ago (about the correct rulings among different spells) is obviously wrong...at that time I was angry with MTG as a whole - because of Ajani's weird rescue -  and tell something like that. I just couldn't stand a situation like Ajani's...see the discussion between Massimiliano and Caleth, that just comes out after this.Thank you Gendolkari!

Comment: But my comment about healing salve comes out AFTER the situation I described in the question. So Gendolkari, I have to say "no,you do not understand" to your second comment. I mean: if i cast healing salve in response of the shock, bears will survive and are able to deal their two point of damage. Ok, in this situation, they obviously deals 6 damages because of the Titanic Growth previously cast...that I forgot in my first comment...

Comment: Allure, I accept your answer because it comes out immediately after; more than this you get through the spirit of the question: there was a change in rulings, and you exactly understood what kind of problem was the one I ask for. But you fail in understanding my comment, instead. Anyhow,it is no capital crime...it is explained better in one of my comments above.

Answer (score 5):

**The Grizzly Bears don't deal combat damage to the Air Elemental**

Assuming no more instants or abilities are added to the stack after Shock, the stack will resolve.

First, Shock will resolve, causing your bears to die.

Then, Titanic Growth will resolve: it can't find the creature you targeted, so it effectively does nothing.

Finally, since the stack is empty and players have passed priority, we move to combat damage. There are no attackers, so no combat damage is dealt.

Comment: "Effectively does nothing" is an understatement. According to the rules (608.2b), it "doesn’t resolve. It’s removed from the 
stack and, if it’s a spell, put into its owner’s graveyard."

Comment: The question was phrased as an either/or rather than yes/no, so I don't think it should be answered with a "no".

Comment: As Arthur pointed out; "Giant Growth will resolve" is incorrect.

Comment: Suggested rewording: "Then, it comes time for Titanic Growth to resolve. But instead of resolving, it's removed from the stack for having no legal targets. It doesn't do anything."

Comment: It sounds good. You are really great in rewording, Ikegami. Please,look after the latest question I have just asked for...